# 2-Level Ruby Ternary Operator Not Working

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

The checks work for integers less than 0 or greater than 100. But can someone tell me **why the 'string not allowed' does not get assigned to intel**?

```
class Human 
    attr_accessor :intel, :agility, :strength 
    def initialize(intel, agility, strength) 
      intel.is_a?(String) ? intel = "string not allowed" : check_range(intel) ? @intel = "Invalid Stat for intel" : @intel = intel 
      check_range(agility) ? @agility = "Invalid Stat for agility" : @agility = agility
      check_range(strength) ? @strength = "Invalid Stat for strength" : @strength = strength   
    end
    def check_range(skill) 
      skill.to_f < 0 || skill.to_f > 100 
    end
    rosetta = Human.new('twenty,26,39) 
    puts rosetta.intel, rosetta.agility, rosetta.strength
end
```

Comment: I'd say this is ternary operator abuse. Writing it out as an `if/elsif/else` statement will make the problem clearer.

Comment: Assigning strings to instance variables is not the Ruby way of indicating errors. You should be raising exceptions or just doing the duck-typing thing and checking that things respond to the necessary methods.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer since it doesn't directly answer your question, but consider refactoring the code like this: https://gist.github.com/cheald/5ad0ca2c61413d26f22b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* getting assigned to `intel`. It is *not* getting assigned to `@intel`, which is maybe what you intended?

You could change that line to

```
@intel = intel.is_a?(String) ? "string not allowed" : check_range(intel) ? "Invalid Stat for intel" : intel
```

But really your code needs some dramatic refactoring. Why the check for `String`? Wouldn't other classes also not be valid? Why store error messages in the variables?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks Max. Thanks August and Chris too.